# Formulas for $\arg\max$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

are any formulas for $\arg\max(f(x))$ known
  (in the context of this question,  $\max(f(x))$ shall denote the essential supremum of $f(x)$ over some given domain $\Omega\subset X$)?

The reason for asking is two-fold

- due to a result of Kantorowitsch the essential supremum (or, *vrai max*, as he called it) can be epressed as $$\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\int_\Omega\left|f(x)\right|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}$$ cf e.g. [this link](https://gbideas.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/integralkerne-in-l-w-kantorowitsch-g-p-akilow-funktionalanalysis-in-normierten-raumen), but I couldn't find an expression for $\arg\max(f(x))$ not even for single elements of that set.
- It seems counter intuitive, that it should not be possible to retrieve elements of $\arg\max(f(x))$ from an expression that yields the essential supremum and thus "should know" where $f(x)$ attains its "maximal" values. I would therefore be surprised to learn that that kind of intuition had not yet been investigated.

In the context of this question, the essential supremum (resp. *vrai max* is defined as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum) and it is further assumed, that $$0\ <\ f(x_0) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}vrai \max \left(f\left(x\in U_\epsilon(x_0)\right)\right)\ <\ +\infty\ \forall x_0\in\bar\Omega$$

I am looking for expressions for (single) elements of $\arg \max(f(x))$, e.g. the one that yields the lexical maximum of $(f(x),x)$.

Comment: It is not the case that $\int |f|^p$ "should know" where $|f|$ is large; in fact, the integral is invariant under rearrangements of $f$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I only used that admittedly naiv and mathematically inacceptable formulation as a motivation for thinking about the problem - freely after the motto "premature mathematical rigor kills creativity". Of course the problem is to find a way of retrieving an argument-value from the function-values alone and I would like to know if someone has already found such a way,.

Comment: In general finding argmax of a function is a much harder problem than finding max, and can require entirely different methods.  There won't be a "formula" of any generality.  Usually the techniques involved will depend on already knowing something about $f$.  As an elementary example, if $f$ is piecewise differentiable, you can look for critical points...

Answer (score -1):

$
    \newcommand{\valArg}{\mathop{\rm arg_{val}}\nolimits}
    \newcommand{\essSup}{\mathop{\rm sup_{ess}}\nolimits}
    \newcommand{\essArg}{\mathop{\rm arg_{ess}}\nolimits}
  $

As there seem to be no kown formulas for calculating elements of arg max and, as the existence of such a formula would seem to come as a surprise, I'd like to present such a formula for discussion.
Provided the formula isn't demonstrated entirely wrong and interest is expressed, I can also provide  ideas for proving its correctness for certain classes of functions.

Before presenting the formula, some clarification regarding terminology is necessary.
Especially different flavors of argument-sets need to be defined; to this end I introduce new operators with the following meaning:

$$
\begin{align}  
& \essSup(f_{|\Omega})\quad := \inf\left\{y\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ \mu\left(f_{|\Omega}^{-1}\left(y,+\infty\right)\right)=0\right\}  \\    
& \valArg(f_{|\Omega},y) := \left\{x\in\Omega\ |\ f(x)=y\right\} \\   
& \essArg(f_{|\Omega},y) := \left\{x\in\overline{\Omega}\ |\ lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\essSup\left(f_{|\Omega\cap U_{\epsilon}(x)}\right)=y\right\}
\end{align}$$
and it is the second set of arguments, that is compatible with the formula of Kantorowitsch and also applicable in cases, where the definition of $\valArg$ is too strict and renders $\valArg\left(f_{|\Omega},\essSup(f_{|\Omega})\right)$ empty.

Now, assuming
$$\begin{align} 
0 & \lt f_{|\Omega} \lt +\infty \\
0 & \lt g_{|\Omega} \lt +\infty\quad \wedge\quad x\not = y \Leftrightarrow g(x) \not = g(y)
\end{align} $$

a candidate formula for an *essential argument* to a function's essential supremum is this one:

> $$\essArg\left(\essSup(f_{|\Omega})\right)\quad\ni\quad
> g^{-1}\left(\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}
> \frac{\essSup\left(\left(f+\epsilon g\right)_{|\Omega}\right)-\essSup\left(f_{|\Omega}\right)}{\epsilon}\right) $$

The benefit of essential arguments is that one has a positive chance of finding arguments in the vincinity, whose function value comes arbitrarily close the value of the essential supremum.

The formula may only be the tip of an iceberg of further investigations, especially in view of pathological functions and their approximation via sequences of well behaved functions.
What may also be possible, is to disqualify conjecture, that are related to the location of zeros, as axioms.
Besides that, it would also be a nice application of the [Gâteau derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative)